# Necessity of closure in word count example in Node.js in Action

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the book Node.js in Action, there is one example where files in directory "./text" is subject to word count. I want to ask if the closure used is actually necessarily or just a matter of style. The code is below:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var completedTasks = 0;
var tasks = [];
var wordCounts = {};
var filesDir = './text';

function checkIfComplete() {
    completedTasks++;
    if (completedTasks == tasks.length) {
        for (var index in wordCounts) {
            console.log(index + ': ' + wordCounts[index]);
        }
    }
}

function countWordsInText(text) {
    var words = text
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(/\W+/)
        .sort()

    for (var index in words) {
        var word = words[index];
        if (word) {
            wordCounts[word] = (wordCounts[word]) ? wordCounts[word] + 1 : 1;
        }
    }
}

// My question is on the use of closure below
fs.readdir(filesDir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var index in files) {
        var task = (function(file) {
            return function() {
                fs.readFile(file, function(err, text) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    countWordsInText(text);
                    checkIfComplete();
                });
            }
        })(filesDir + '/' + files[index]);
        tasks.push(task);
    }

    for (var task in tasks) {
        tasks[task]();
    }
});
```

This code is used in the book to demonstrate the nature of parallel control flow. My question is why does the code goes through this seemingly twisted elaboration (sorry, lol, a newbie here) of constructing closure then calling them? (I'm referring to the each task in tasks.)

Is that any different from what comes more natural to me like so?

```
fs.readdir(filesDir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    tasks = files; // Just to make sure the check for completion runs fine.
    for (var index in files) {
        var file = files[index];
        fs.readFile(filesDir + '/' +  file, function(err, text) {
            if (err) throw err;
            countWordsInText(text);
            checkIfComplete();
        });
    }
});
```

Wouldn't it still be asynchronous and as "parallel" as it was in the previous code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to avoid the closure here. The closure would be required to avoid the infamous [closure-in-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) gotcha which *would* happen if the callback passed to `fs.readFile` accessed the loop variable or something derived from it. Because then, by the time the callback would be called, the value of the loop variable would be the last value assigned to it.

The way you do it is okay. I've not tried to completely clean the code or make it resilient to faults but I'd do:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var wordCounts = Object.create(null);
var filesDir = './text';

function countWordsInText(text) {
    var words = text
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(/\W+/)
        .sort();

    for (var index in words) {
        var word = words[index];
        if (word) {
            wordCounts[word] = (wordCounts[word]) ? wordCounts[word] + 1 : 1;
        }
    }
}

fs.readdir(filesDir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var total = files.length;
    var completedTasks = 0;
    for (var index in files) {
        fs.readFile(filesDir + '/' + files[index], function(err, text) {
            if (err) throw err;
            countWordsInText(text);
            completedTasks++;
            if (completedTasks === total) {
                for (var index in wordCounts) {
                    console.log(index + ': ' + wordCounts[index]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```